# Regular Perturbation Series soln to eqn

Tags: perturbation, applied-mathematics, asymptotics, na.numerical-analysis

I want to find the a 3 term perturbation soln of
(i)   $(1+x)^3 = ex$    where $e\ll1$

Direct substitution of the regular perturbation series $x = x_0 + ex_1 + e^2x_2$ 
into (i) does not work

I think soln has the form: $x = x_0 + e^{1/3}*x_1 + e^{2/3}*x_2$
Seems to work, but not sure it is correct

TIA,
Matt

Comment: Does this arise from a modelling problem, or is it an exercise somewhere?

Comment: It is an exercise from Logan's applied math book. I am trying to learn perturbation methods and he seems to have a pretty decent intro to the subject. To be specific, it is problem 7, on page 101. Incidentally, if you happen to have the text, there is what appears to be a very fun problem directly preceding it, which I believe is a generalization of this problem, but which I have not yet been able to crack either.
I am not sure the soln admits of a regular perturbation series, but if you play around with it a bit, it seems like it must be.

Comment: This is not my area, and I don't know the book, but I'm not sure the question is really on topic for the site, see http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot

Comment: I would have thought that you want $x$ to be a small perturbation of $-1$...

Comment: unknown: a good opportunity for you to use the Lagrange inversion formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since  $e$ is small, the solution $x$ is close to $-1$. So write $x=-1+u$ and write your equation as $u(1-u)^{-1/3}=-e^{1/3}$. Then use the [Lagrange inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#The_Lagrange_inversion_formula).

Comment: rmk: This gives a series expansion of $x=-1+u$ in powers of $e^{1/3}$. For large values of $e$ write instead the equation as $x(1+x)^{-3}=1/e$, and get an expansion of the solution in powers of $1/e$.
  

Comment: That is such a beautiful theorem. I knew the solution worked but I didn't know why. I knew there had to be a "formal" justification for why this power series worked, and this is spot on.
Thank you so much for introducing me to such a beautiful result!!

Comment: To Yemon,
1) Yes, x is close to -1, this is the point of the problem (which is that regular perturbation series will not work if one tries x=-1+e*x1+...)
2) I don't understand why my post is not appropriate as I:
    a) am not a student
    b) am not trying to start a discussion
    c) I did not ask for a definition of a term (i.e. my problem had an answer)
    d) Did not ask a question about MathOverLow.
Please correct me if I am wrong or violated the site's policy in some other way, as I respect MathOverflow and do not want to abuse it in any way.
Thanks,
Matt